# monitor command outputs in separate windows within a terminal

Tags: bash, shell

For a list of input text, I want to execute a repetitive command using each element from the list. In addition I also need to monitor the results of each of these commands in parallel. So I am looking for a solution to display the repetitive commands output in separate windows in a single terminal console; probably need a form of terminal multiplexer?

So far I have the following:

```
for i in `command1 find msgs/Poly`; do echo command2 echo "$i" ; multitail -l 'command2 echo "$i"' ; done
```

which seems to open only one window at a time.

Comment: do you need to actually SEE all of the results in parallel, or do you just need them to run in parallel and all dump output in separate screens?  If it is the latter, consider the `screen` command

Comment: @RussellUhl I need to see all the results in parallel.